# Git: Equivalent of `--full-history` for `git bisect` and `git blame`

Tags: git, version-control, git-log, git-bisect, git-blame

I've been using Git heavily for about 7 years. A few days ago I found a behavior that surprised me. I found `git log`, `git blame` and `git bisect` to exhibit this weird behavior. [A friend](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgithg/) let me know about the `--full-history` flag to `git log` that solved my problem. I want to know, for my own education, whether there is an equivalent fix for `git blame` and `git bisect`.

Feel free to see the problem for yourself with this repo: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1927707/problematic_repo.7z

Here is its log:

```
$ git log  --graph
* commit b7a8d7aa001d06eb7491ab5fb447a8dd3aa421a8
| Author: Ram Rachum <ram@rachum.com>
| Date:   Tue Apr 19 17:45:01 2016 +0300
|
|     adding more to some-file
|
*   commit 0aa833916e908ea93902a6c4c227f9a884a1bcef
|\  Merge: 2413945 3068c7d
| | Author: Ram Rachum <ram@rachum.com>
| | Date:   Tue Apr 19 17:44:31 2016 +0300
| |
| |     Merge branch 'master' into development
| |
| * commit 3068c7d2548f1798b6840f73b13a649937339f28
| | Author: Ram Rachum <ram@rachum.com>
| | Date:   Tue Apr 19 16:02:27 2016 +0300
| |
| |     Adding sugar to coffee
| |
* | commit 24139451ab954b1f0a9ef616775a3dba0ac81669
|/  Author: Ram Rachum <ram@rachum.com>
|   Date:   Tue Apr 19 16:01:28 2016 +0300
|
|       Creating some-file
|
* commit cf02fbbc40104cd02eea4c7c6f134ef1fd7b5661
  Author: Ram Rachum <ram@rachum.com>
  Date:   Tue Apr 19 16:00:47 2016 +0300

      Create coffee
```

In the very first commit, the file `coffee` was added. In the commit `3068c7d`, I added a line "sugar" to the `coffee` file. But then I merged this branch into the `development` branch, and in that merge, a mistake was made and the "sugar" line was removed, leaving `coffee` empty. Then another commit `b7a8d7a`, making an unrelated change, was added for good measure.

Now I'm looking at my coffee, and finding there's no sugar in it. I distinctly remember adding sugar to my coffee. I run `git log coffee`, and get this output:

```
$ git log coffee
commit cf02fbbc40104cd02eea4c7c6f134ef1fd7b5661
Author: Ram Rachum <ram@rachum.com>
Date:   Tue Apr 19 16:00:47 2016 +0300

    Create coffee
```

That's it. `git log` is showing neither my original commit that added the sugar, nor the merge that removed it. Two very relevant commits that are missing.

I was frustrated for about an hour by this problem, because it happened in a huge enterprise repo, where commits are much harder to find manually.

I also tried using `git bisect` and `git blame` to pin down the two commits, but both of these tools ignored the two commits. `git bisect` pointed me to the wrong commit after I finished doing all the `git bisect bad` and `git bisect good` actions.

Then, as I said in the beginning, a friend pointed me towards the `--full-history` flag:

```
$ git log --full-history --graph coffee                
*   commit 0aa833916e908ea93902a6c4c227f9a884a1bcef    
|\  Merge: cf02fbb 3068c7d                             
| | Author: Ram Rachum <ram@rachum.com>                
| | Date:   Tue Apr 19 17:44:31 2016 +0300             
| |                                                    
| |     Merge branch 'master' into development         
| |                                                    
| * commit 3068c7d2548f1798b6840f73b13a649937339f28    
|/  Author: Ram Rachum <ram@rachum.com>                
|   Date:   Tue Apr 19 16:02:27 2016 +0300             
|                                                      
|       Adding sugar to coffee                         
|                                                      
* commit cf02fbbc40104cd02eea4c7c6f134ef1fd7b5661      
  Author: Ram Rachum <ram@rachum.com>                  
  Date:   Tue Apr 19 16:00:47 2016 +0300               

      Create coffee
```

This makes me happy because it shows the two relevant commits, the one adding sugar and the merge that removed it. So my problem is solved. **But I really wish I could know how to make `git bisect` and `git blame` behave as well.** Does anyone happen to know?

Comment: `git blame` might well allow `--full-history` directly here (I would try it on your repo but I cannot unpack a 7zip file).  Bisect might refuse to touch merges since it handles them itself.  In general you aren't seeing these because `git rev-list` skips a lot of merges: see the documentation's discussion on TREESAME and merge handling (and how --full-history alters this).

Comment: @torek I tried it now, `blame` appears to accept the flag but it looks like it doesn't change anything. Trying both `git blame --full-history` and `git blame --full-history --reverse` showed no results. Regarding not being able to open 7z archives, here it is in zip: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1927707/foo.zip

Comment: @torek Also tried `git blame --reverse HEAD^^^..HEAD --full-history coffee` , still getting nothing.

Comment: Not really trying to give you a silver bullet here but you might find https://github.com/dreamyguy/gitlogg useful to parse all your commits to `JSON` so that you can have a good clinical look at them. You might want to uncomment all the commented-out fields on the `gitlogg-parse-json.js` file and remove the `--no-merges` on the `gitlogg-generate-log.sh` to get all the output available.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting.  Since the line isn't there, `git blame` starts out quite unhelpful.  As the documentation for `git blame` notes:

> The report does not tell you anything about lines which have been
>     deleted or replaced; you need to use a tool such as git diff or the
>     "pickaxe" interface briefly mentioned in the following paragraph.

In this case we might run `git log -SSugar` to find where it went in:

```
$ git log --pretty=oneline -SSugar
3068c7d2548f1798b6840f73b13a649937339f28 Adding sugar to coffee
```

but `git blame` won't immediately help us find where it went out.  (And as you have just discovered, if we want to find that line when mentioning files, we may need `--full-history`, since adding path(s) to limit the commits `git log` will consider, also causes history simplification by pruning each commit's tree to contain just the mentioned files and then using that `TREESAME` code.)

Starting from the known-good rev, we can now try `--reverse` [**edit**: I noticed `3068c7d2548f1798b6840f73b13a649937339f28` == `master` and actually used `master` here, probably should have used the SHA-1 directly]:

```
$ git blame --reverse master..HEAD coffee
^3068c7d (Ram Rachum 2016-04-19 16:02:27 +0300 1) Sugar
```

This seems to imply that `3068c7d` is the last rev in which the line exists, so it must be deleted in some or all of the children along this particular path, which is true:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all
* b7a8d7a (HEAD -> development) adding more to some-file
*   0aa8339 Merge branch 'master' into development
|\  
| * 3068c7d (master) Adding sugar to coffee
* | 2413945 Creating some-file
|/  
* cf02fbb Create coffee
```

There is only one commit that is a child of `3068c7d` here, namely `0aa8339`, so:

```
$ git show -m 0aa8339
commit 0aa833916e908ea93902a6c4c227f9a884a1bcef (from 3068c7d2548f1798b6840f73b1
Merge: 2413945 3068c7d
Author: Ram Rachum <ram@rachum.com>
Date:   Tue Apr 19 17:44:31 2016 +0300

    Merge branch 'master' into development

diff --git a/coffee b/coffee
index 4d0f160..e69de29 100644
--- a/coffee
+++ b/coffee
@@ -1 +0,0 @@
-Sugar
diff --git a/some-file b/some-file
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..e69de29
```

(we need `-m` to get git to compare the merge against both parents).  And that does find it, in a slightly roundabout way.

---

(Meanwhile, there seems to be no cure for the bisect issue.  Well, other than "avoid evil merges"...)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My mistake with `--reverse` was not using the correct left commit.

Comment: Update: I tried using `blame` now for a similar case, but where the old commit removed the lines that existed before, and the merge mistakenly re-added them. `blame` failed to show the merge that mistakenly re-added the lines, even when I used `--full-history` and `--full-history --reverse branch..other_branch`. Any idea why?

Comment: I'm not really sure: I do not use `git blame` all that much myself.  In general, though, whether it's going forward or reverse, it just compares (the lines of a file in) each before/after commit, taken pairwise, to see if a line was changed or removed.  The line then gets assigned the ID of the corresponding commit of the pair.  This method does not (and cannot) work very well across merges since there are multiple pairings.